# Using 7A power cord on 10A laptop

Tags: laptop, power-supply

Does using a 7A power cord on a laptop that needs 10A damage components or mess something up? I know I need a new one but I have already used the old power cord. This laptop is a Compaq Armada 1500 computer (20+ years old).

Comment: Are you referring to the mains lead or the lead from the mains adapter to the computer? If the former, it will be ok as the adapter will not be drawing even 5 A from the mains; if the latter I would be concerned about the lead overheating and melting or catching fire.

Comment: Well the adapter is built inside the computer. It is just a cord with no adapter that goes from the wall tongue computer. The adapter inside the computer needs at least 10A and the cord only supports 7A.

Comment: If the laptop is drawing even 5 A from the mains then it will be generating 600 W of heat (assuming 120 V mains) - think of a small electric fan heater - which is unlikely. Are you asking because it has a connector rated at 10 A?

Comment: The manual said it needed 10A for some reason. Everything makes sense now though. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the computer really does draw more then 7 amps (which be very unlikely - even at only 100 volts that would be 770 watts  which would drain the battery in seconds to minutes and the laptop would need to disipate an impractical amount if heat ) this could theoretically be dangerous as the cord would heat up and possibly short out - so its a fire risk.

If this is a British plug with a 5 amp or 7 amp fuse in the base, it is ok to use. If not, the risk is very small [but not non existant. It would be a question if " why did the manufacturer specify a 10 amp cable?" My guess us that they were cheap and standard  and not to do with the laptop requirements.